# Mysql query with multiples conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

I have to get products in multiples categories (Prestashop database).

This my query :

```
SELECT COUNT( cp.`id_product` ) AS total
FROM  `ps_product` p
INNER JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON ( product_shop.id_product = p.id_product
AND product_shop.id_shop =1 ) 
LEFT JOIN  `ps_category_product` cp ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product` 
WHERE cp.`id_category` =6
AND cp.`id_category` =126
AND product_shop.`visibility` 
IN (
"both",  "catalog"
)
AND product_shop.`active` =1
```

I want to select inside category 6 AND inside category 126, but my query return 0.

A product can have multiples categories, so i want to select only if products are inside the two categories.

How can this be fixed, so I am getting the expected result?

Comment: Insted of  cp.id_category =6
AND cp.id_category =126. Use cp.id_category in(6,126). Check full code below.

Comment: Insted of Inner join use Left join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT( cp.id_product ) AS total
FROM  ps_product p
Left JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON ( product_shop.id_product = p.id_product
                                            AND product_shop.id_shop =1 ) 
LEFT JOIN  ps_category_product cp ON p.id_product = cp.id_product 
WHERE cp.id_category in(6,126)
    AND product_shop.visibility IN ('both',  'catalog')
    AND product_shop.active =1
```

Friend Try this,

```
SELECT COUNT( cp.id_product ) AS total
FROM  ps_product p
Left JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON ( product_shop.id_product = p.id_product
                                            AND product_shop.id_shop =1 ) 
LEFT JOIN  ps_category_product cp ON p.id_product = cp.id_product 
            and cp.id_category in(6)
LEFT JOIN  ps_category_product cp1 ON p.id_product = cp1.id_product 
            and cp1.id_category in(126)
WHERE cp.id_category is not null
    and cp1.id_category is not null
    AND product_shop.visibility IN ('both',  'catalog')
    AND product_shop.active =1
```

Comment: It returns products in category 6 and category 126 but not products only inside these 2 categories

Comment: What does mean by inside? please provide example.

Comment: I have two products in category 6. I have 3 products in category 126. Only one product has category 6 AND 126 so, i want only 1 result!

Comment: So you want product, which is there in both categories?

Comment: Still searching for best option.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
WHERE cp.`id_category` =6
OR cp.`id_category` =126
```

Comment: Not that. i want only products with theses categories, not all inside category 6 and all inside category 126

Answer (score 0):

Do u mean between 6 and 126? It is not possible to validate against one column for both 6 and 126. If it is between then use,

```
SELECT COUNT( cp.`id_product` ) AS total
FROM  `ps_product` p
INNER JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON ( product_shop.id_product = p.id_product
AND product_shop.id_shop =1 ) 
LEFT JOIN  `ps_category_product` cp ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product` 
WHERE cp.`id_category` between 6 and 126
AND product_shop.`visibility` 
IN (
"both",  "catalog"
)
AND product_shop.`active` =1
```

Comment: No only in category 6 AND 126

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (cp.`id_category` = 6 OR cp.`id_category` = 126)
AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both",  "catalog")
AND product_shop.`active` = 1
```

In both categories:

```
SELECT COUNT( cp.id_product ) AS total
FROM  ps_product p
Left JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON (product_shop.id_product = p.id_product
                                           AND product_shop.id_shop = 1)     
WHERE product_shop.visibility IN ('both',  'catalog')
  AND product_shop.active = 1
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ps_category_product cp 
             WHERE p.id_product = cp.id_product AND cp.id_category = 6)
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ps_category_product cp 
             WHERE p.id_product = cp.id_product AND cp.id_category = 12)
```